# move files from multiple source to multiple destination in one command

Tags: ssh, scp, mv

I am running ssh command and doing move command in it.

```
ssh $USER_ID@$DESTINATION_SERVER "mv /source /destination"
```

This is working fine. But I have to do this with multiple files in many source and destination directories. If I repeat the command then it will ask for password everytime.
Please help.

Comment: separate your commands using `;` ? ex: `cmd1 ; cmd2 ; cmd3` .. but perhaps there is a better way

Comment: Use SSH keys (and agent) so you don't need to repeat the password each time. Or just log in and run all the commands from a remote shell (which would give you tab-completion too)

Answer (score 0):

Separating the command using ; worked.

```
ssh $USER_ID@$DESTINATION_SERVER "mv /source1/* /destination1/; mv /source2/ /destination2/; ......"
```

Comment: if you don't need to use any local variables (or command substitution etc) in that ssh command, use single-quotes rather than double.  BTW, another method is to write a script to do what you want, `scp` it to the remote system (e.g. `scp myscript user@remote:/tmp` and execute it with ssh, e.g. `ssh user@remote bash /tmp/myscript`.   Finally, use key-based authentication rather than a password.  basic setup is as easy as running 'ssh-keygen` followed by `ssh-copy-id user@remotehost`.